# Time format in momentjs that has number of day prefix

Tags: momentjs, time-format

How can we use momentjs for a time format that has a number of day part prefix?
We can use:

```
moment("19:41:00", "HH:mm:ss");
```

What is the time format for:

> 28.19:41:00

Thanks for helping.

Comment: use like this: moment("19:41:00", "[prefix] HH:mm:ss [suffix]");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let date = this.moment("28.19:41:00", "DD.HH:mm:ss");
console.log(date.format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss"));      // 2019/12/28 19:41:00
console.log(date.format("HH:mm:ss"));                 // 19:41:00
```